# Can I name a group of workbooks for later use in a module?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of file paths to some Excel workbooks in an Excel spreadsheet. For example:

```
D:\SomeWorkbook.xlsx
D:\SomeOtherWorkbook.xlsx
D:\AnotherWorkbook.xlsx
etc...
```

If I open all of these, for example:

```
Set wkb1 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="D:\SomeWorkbook.xlsx", WriteResPassword:="x")
Set wkb2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="D:\SomeOtherWorkbook.xlsx", WriteResPassword:="x")
Set wkb3 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="D:\AnotherWorkbook.xlsx", WriteResPassword:="x")
Set wkb4 = etc.
```

And let's say I do a count to find that the list contains 6 file paths or 5 file paths, etc.; is there a way to assign a "group" name to these 5 or 6 or however many workbooks? So that I can do something like "for each wkb in wkbGroup, do something"? Please note that I will have other workbooks open that I do not want in this "group".

All the workbooks contain a "sheet1". Ultimately I will be cycling through all the workbooks in the "group" and will be processing data from sheet1 of each workbook in the "group"

Comment: just loop all the open workbooks: `For Each wkb In Workbooks` and `If wkb.Name <> "NametoSkip" then`

Comment: You could also create an array of workbooks: `Dim wkbks(1 to 4) as workbook` then set them `Set wkbks(1) = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="D:\SomeWorkbook.xlsx", WriteResPassword:="x")` etc.  Then loop that array.

Comment: Ugh... Ok... I will try that... I hadn't thought about doing it that way... To clarify... There is no way to name a "group" of workbooks?

Comment: @XCELLGUY you cannot apply the same name to several open workbooks (excel can only have one open at a time of the same name, even if different versions [shoutout to sharepoint users with version history...]), just as it cannot name every file in a folder the same name (basic windows OS).  Scott posted the `for each` loop for you; just remember that you can put in *other* checks, such as sheet names, or even a cell value in a hidden sheet, before you do anything with/to that current workbook in the loop.

Comment: @XCELLGUY You could "name a group" of workbooks by making an array like `mywkbks = Array("Workbook1", "Workbook2", "Workbook3")` then loop through that.

Comment: the workbooks all have different names

Comment: Thank you all... I will start playing around with these ideas and see if I can figure something out....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
Dim wb
For each wb in MyWb()
    'do something with wb
Next wb



'return a collection of all open workbooks listed on sheet "list"
Function MyWb() as Collection
    Dim wb As Workbook, col as new collection
    For each wb in Workbooks
        If not iserror(application.match(wb.fullname,
                       ThisWorkbook.Sheets("list").range("A:A"),0)) Then
            col.add wb
        End if
    next wb
    Set mywb = col
End function
```

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I was looking for. Especially since there will be several places throughout my code where I will need to iterate through this "collection" of workbooks. When I was wording my question I thought what I might be looking for was a "collection" but I was afraid to mention that in case I was barking up the wrong tree. This solution has resulted in me Google searching collections to learn about them. However, I came across several articles that compare them to being similar to arrays and several articles explaining when to use collections instead of an array.

Comment: Now I am confused as to whether I should use an array? or a collection? I am having trouble even determining if you can store objects in an array? Can an array store objects? (objects like workbooks for example)

Comment: Arrays can store anything (including objects) but have the overhead of needing to manage the size (upper/lower bounds) so using a Collection is more convenient in many cases - you can add/remove items with a single line without the hassle of `Redim` etc you have to deal with when using arrays..

Comment: Thank you... I think collection may be easier for me in this situation... but I will try some things tomorrow and see